# creating a new php/html page with a given template in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been trying to make a new php/html page with a template of a page that I made.

**Background:** 
I have a form to add a new product in my shop website, I made a form that when filled out and sent(admin tools), adds the properties of the product into a database(using mysql). In addition to adding the product to a database I wanted to actually create a page for the product.

What I've done is before exiting the script that inserts all the variables/properties into the database, creating a file with the that has those properties. I managed to create the file and made a template for inserting variables into the html section.

**My problem:**
When I create the page and write into it the template, I thought that the code will replace the variables that are in the template before inserting it.

**here is my code and example:**

```
$template = file_get_contents("../product_template.php");
$page = fopen("../$link", "x");
fwrite($page, "$template");
```

**part of my template***:

```
<ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <?php
                    if($target == "men"){
                        echo '<li><a href="categories%20-%20Men.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Men\'s</a></li>';
                    }
                    elseif($target == "women"){
                        echo '<li><a href="categories%20-%20Women.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Women\'s</a></li>';
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<li><a href="categories%20-%20Couple.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Couple\'s</a></li>';
                    }


                    echo "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-angle-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i>\"$name\"</a></li>";
                    ?>

                </ul>


                                <?php
                                echo "<li><img src=\"images/\"$secondPic\" alt=\"\" data-image=\"images/\"$secondPic\"\"></li>";
                                echo "<li class=\"active\"><img src=\"images/\"$mainPic\"\" alt=\"\" data-image=\"images/\"$mainPic\"\"></li>";
                                echo "<li><img src=\"images/\"$thirdPic\" alt=\"\" data-image=\"images/\"$thirdPic\"\"></li>";
                                ?>
                            </ul>
```

*deleted some html tags so the code will look a bit cleaner

how do I add the template to the page so that the script recognizes the if statments and variables inside the template.
**One thing I thought of doing is:**

adding another button to create a page for a specific and in that script pull the data from the data base and after the template adding the "create page functions",

What do you think? should I separate the codes or is it possible to run the code inside the template before writing into the new page?
sorry if my post is a bit of a mess, I'm very confused myself about what I need to do and should do in order to solve my problem.

*thank you!*

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.

What I was wrong is thinking that copying the content that the template page had would automatically fill in the variables and if statements, what actually was happening is that I made the template page a string, which when inserted into the new page, was literally pasting all the content including the variables and the if statements.

adding all the variables and asking the if statements before inserting the html code into a variable and than pasting the code into a new page.